# How to write Integration Test for @Component class which have spring repository code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am writing Junit test cases for the following class @Component class.I am actually using Sql Server for my original application.But, as part of testing i am using in memory h2 db .And I want to test this class without starting Original application.If I use repository in test class,i can see data returned in test,but exactly when I call the void method inside @Component class getting NULL pointer.
Here is my code.

```
    @Component
    public class CandidatesTableServiceImpl {



        @Autowired
        private CandidatesTableRepository candidatesTableRepository;

        @Transactional
        public void getAllRecordsFromCandidateTable() throws ParseException {

            List<CandidatesTable> customerRecord = candidatesTableRepository
                    .findByStatus(status);

/** This method throwing Null pointer exception when calling from method **/


    }
```

my src/test/reources/application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
# Create DDL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And my Test class looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@Transactional
public class CandidateTableTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    CandidatesTableRepository candidatesTableRepository;

    String status;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        CandidatesTableServiceImpl candidatesTableServiceImpl= new candidatesTableServiceImpl()

    }

    @Test
    public void checkSaveMethod() throws ParseException {

        CandidatesTable candidatesTable = new CandidatesTable();

        candidatesTable.setStatus(status);
        candidatesTable.setCandidatesTableID(1);
        candidatesTable.setAccountNumber("2000321654");

        candidatesTableRepository.save(candidatesTable);
        this.entityManager.persist(candidatesTable);


/** This method works fine **/
                  List<CandidatesTable> alertRecord = candidatesTableRepository.findByStatus(status);


/** This method throwing NUll Pointer excption **/
        candidatesTableServiceImpl.getAllRecordsFromCandidateTable();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify where to scan the components, use

```
@ComponentScan(value = ["your.package.name"])
```

also you need to flush data

```
   @Test
   public void checkSaveMethod() throws ParseException {

       CandidatesTable candidatesTable = new CandidatesTable();

       candidatesTable.setStatus(status);
       candidatesTable.setCandidatesTableID(1);
       candidatesTable.setAccountNumber("2000321654");

       candidatesTableRepository.save(candidatesTable);
       this.entityManager.persist(candidatesTable);
       this.entityManager.flush();

/** This method works fine **/
                 List<CandidatesTable> alertRecord = candidatesTableRepository.findByStatus(status);


/** This method throwing NUll Pointer excption **/
       candidatesTableServiceImpl.getAllRecordsFromCandidateTable();

   }
```

Comment: I tried with @ComponentScan getting the same issue.